# Line plots from two different data frames and Error- Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I am trying to create a line plot taking y values from two different data frames. However, I keep on encountering the error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale. I have tried using as.numeric and have tried to scale the axis but it still does not work for me.

Example of the two dataframes:

```
structure(list(Years = 1961:1980, GDP.growth = c(13.2341274874115, 
6.56992026378001, 11.6494473111434, 7.70627301508087, 3.2139048259846, 
1.42190836629628, 6.46229426379345, 5.3432872663989, 0.068147071333243, 
-5.54665996976902, 10.3970656983541, 4.29783746387267, -2.63683712200368, 
3.84659112655312, -1.79430023712248, 10.9319135379163, 13.5245271383117, 
5.17203033856374, -0.0649726864368176, 2.38241807770588)), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

```
structure(list(GCF.at.Mp = c(8.8, 8.8, 8, 6.7, 8.3, 9.2, 10, 
9.5, 8.1, 7.4, 7.6, 8.9, 8.4, 8.5, 8.4, 8.8, 9.3, 9.9, 10.1, 
10.3), Years = c("1950", "1951", "1952", "1953", "1954", "1955", 
"1956", "1957", "1958", "1959", "1960", "1961", "1962", "1963", 
"1964", "1965", "1966", "1967", "1968", "1969")), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

The base code that I have tried to use:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data=WBDATA, aes(x=Years), y=GDP.growth), color='darkblue') + 
  geom_line(data=ES.DATA, aes(x=Years, y=GCF.at.Mp), color='darkred', linetype= "twodash")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different solution would be first convert your years from your WBDATA as `character`. Next set in the `aes` of both lines `group = 1`. To add a second scale (not necessary) use `scale_y_continuous` with `sec.axis`. And finally if you want, you can rotate the years on x-axis in the `theme`. You can use the following code:

```
WBDATA$Years <- as.character(WBDATA$Years)

library(tidyverse)
ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data=WBDATA, aes(x=Years, y=GDP.growth, group = 1), color='darkblue') + 
  geom_line(data=ES.DATA, aes(x=Years, y=GCF.at.Mp, group = 1), color='darkred', linetype= "twodash") +
  scale_y_continuous(
    "GCF", 
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ ., name = "GDP")
  ) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I would be hesitant to convert years to character, as the scale will be wrong if there are any years with no data. It works with these data, but I wouldn’t recommend as a general practice.

Answer (score 2):

Convert Years of your second dataframe to numeric, which can be done within ggplot:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data=WBDATA, aes(x=Years, y=GDP.growth), color='darkblue') + 
  geom_line(data=ES.DATA, aes(x=as.numeric(Years), y=GCF.at.Mp), color='darkred', linetype= "twodash")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`df2$Years` is of class character (discrete scale) and not double (continuous scale). You can convert everything to character before joining them together. Then you can convert the types back. Its easier if you have one merged data frame for plotting, because they both share the same x axis:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- structure(list(Years = 1961:1980, GDP.growth = c(
  13.2341274874115,
  6.56992026378001, 11.6494473111434, 7.70627301508087, 3.2139048259846,
  1.42190836629628, 6.46229426379345, 5.3432872663989, 0.068147071333243,
  -5.54665996976902, 10.3970656983541, 4.29783746387267, -2.63683712200368,
  3.84659112655312, -1.79430023712248, 10.9319135379163, 13.5245271383117,
  5.17203033856374, -0.0649726864368176, 2.38241807770588
)), row.names = c(
  NA,
  20L
), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(GCF.at.Mp = c(
  8.8, 8.8, 8, 6.7, 8.3, 9.2, 10,
  9.5, 8.1, 7.4, 7.6, 8.9, 8.4, 8.5, 8.4, 8.8, 9.3, 9.9, 10.1,
  10.3
), Years = c(
  "1950", "1951", "1952", "1953", "1954", "1955",
  "1956", "1957", "1958", "1959", "1960", "1961", "1962", "1963",
  "1964", "1965", "1966", "1967", "1968", "1969"
)), row.names = c(
  NA,
  20L
), class = "data.frame")



df <-
  list(df1, df2) %>%
  # unify column classes
  map(~ .x %>% mutate(across(everything(), as.character))) %>%
  reduce(full_join) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  type_convert()
#> Joining, by = "Years"
#> ── Column specification
#> ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────── cols( Years =
#> col_double(), GDP.growth = col_double(), GCF.at.Mp = col_double() )

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(Years)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = GDP.growth), color = "darkblue") +
  geom_line(aes(y = GCF.at.Mp), color = "darkred")
#> Warning: Removed 11 row(s) containing missing values (geom_path).
#> Removed 11 row(s) containing missing values (geom_path).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>